# hotmail not receiving image attachment content

Tags: email, attachment, mime, hotmail

I'm trying to send a raw email with image attachments via AmazonSES using PHP. It works great when I send the email to a gmail account but hotmail accounts are receiving empty attached images. In other words, hotmail seems to recognize that there are attachments and these attachments have the correct name that i specified, it's just that they are always empty, sized 0 bytes. Googling is not helping... Thanks in advance!

```
$amazonSES = new AmazonSES();

// if (empty($attach)==0) {
    // $response = $amazonSES->send_email(AWS_SES_FROM_EMAIL,
        // array('ToAddresses' => array($to)),
        // array('Subject.Data' => $subject,'Body.Text.Data' => $messagein,)
    // );
// } else {
    $rstring = 'ajfas90lsjhntlen89y34oi598';

    $message= "To: ".$to."\n";
    $message.= "From: " . AWS_SES_FROM_EMAIL . "\n";
    $message.= "Subject: " . $subject . "\n";
    $message.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $message.= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="ARandomString'.$rstring.'"';
    $message.= "\n\n";
    $message.= "--ARandomString$rstring\n";
    $message.= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"';
    $message.= "\n";
    $message.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
    $message.= "Content-Disposition: inline\n";
    $message.= "\n";
    $message.= $messagein;
    $message.= "\n\n";
    $message.= "--ARandomString$rstring\n";

    foreach ($attach as $attachment) {
        // $message.= "Content-ID: \<77987_SOME_WEIRD_TOKEN_BUT_UNIQUE_SO_SOMETIMES_A_@domain.com_IS_ADDED\>\n";
        $message.= "Content-ID: \<". md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) ."@biomechanico.com\>\n";
        $message.= 'Content-Type: application/zip; name="shell.zip"';
        $message.= "\n";
        $message.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $message.= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $attachment["name"] . '"';
        $message.= "\n" . base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment["file"])) . "\n";
        $message.= "--ARandomString$rstring\n";
    }

    $response = $amazonSES->send_raw_email(array(
                    'Data'=> base64_encode($message)),
                         array('Source'=>AWS_SES_FROM_EMAIL, 'Destinations'=> $to));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are producing a malformed message.

Consider using a proper library for generating mail messages, instead of stitching them together from raw strings.

Otherwise, here’s what I notice right away.

1. The final multipart boundary must be terminated by an extra `--`, i.e. the last line must be:

`--ARandomStringajfas90lsjhntlen89y34oi598--`

rather than

`--ARandomStringajfas90lsjhntlen89y34oi598`

2. In the attachment parts, you do not have a blank line between the `Content-Disposition` header line and the body.
3. Message lines must not be longer than 998 characters, but your Base64-encoded attachment data, however long, is always on a single line.
4. As far as I understand PHP, your syntax for `Content-ID` in the attachment parts is wrong, in that it produces `Content-ID: \<whatever\>` but should produce `Content-ID: <whatever>`
5. Lines must be terminated by CR LF (`\r\n`), but you have LF (`\n`).

A good way to debug message problems is to take the actual full generated message source (`$message`) and run it through [Message Lint](http://www.apps.ietf.org/content/message-lint). If the above suggestions do not help, please post the generated message source rather than the PHP code.

For the Internet message format, please refer to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). For the multipart message syntax, please refer to [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046).

Comment: These solved my problem thank you. I tried to use PHPmailer but couldn't figure out how to get it to work with amazonses. Thanks again

Comment: @nbunderson You probably need to call something like [`getSentMIMEMessage`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_getSentMIMEMessage) and assign the resulting string to `$message`.